# Delete/merge mutliple vertices on the same spot

Tags: modeling, vertices

My problem can be seen in the pics below... I want to edit this part of the model but I can't select the vertex that connects all the edges that seem to be attatched to it. Instead, I have to delete three layers of vertices on the same spot (and lose some faces too), in order to find the desired vertex. I am pretty sure I have never extruded or done any transformation around there.

This happens way too often while modeling and I spend too much time deleting vetrices and "rebuilding" lost faces. Is there any tool that can help me fix this?

Thanks in advance

[image]

Desired outcome (without losing faces):

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Select every vertex with <kbd>A</kbd>, hit <kbd>W</kbd> and select *remove doubles* .
 you may have to adjust the merge distance if they are not exactly on the same spot.
[image]

To make vertices that are on the same location merge automatically, enable automerge.
[image]

---

Another option is to select all the vertices again with <kbd>A</kbd> then press <kbd>Space</kbd> to open the search, then type Remove doubles (Or for saving time, just "dou")

Then press enter or click on it.

[image: search]

Comment: That was fast and spot on!! Thank you friend!!